# Visual Studio 2008 crashes when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a solution filled entirely with .NET 3.5 projects (so the 2.0 CLR) - today after rebuilding my project (and having made only minor changes to the codebase) I rebuilt it and hit Debug.

Immediately VS crashed to the desktop. The Application Event Log had this entry:

> .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3625 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A05AE08) (80131506)

I relaunched VS and tried again, hitting Debug straight away (without a rebuild)

> .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3625 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (000006427F827D6F) (0)

I cleaned the solution, rebuilt it, and I still get this problem.

I haven't rebooted just yet, but I'll give that a try in a few minutes.

My computer has been switched off the past week, but I don't think that has anything to do with it.

I've tried searching the web for these error codes, there was only one relevant result[1] which suggested running this utility[2], however when I ran the utility it told me that all of my .NET Framework installations were correctly configured with no corruption detected.

[1] http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/938126ed-c98d-4c9c-94d4-aedd22a27822

[2] http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx

Unfortunately it's a weekend, and Microsoft's VS support team are only available Monday to Friday.

UPDATE:

I rebooted, but I still get the same problem. My system has every Windows Update installed too.

Comment: at least try to reboot first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a 3-day support incident with Microsoft over this. In the end it was found-out that a third-party VS add-in: Huagati DBML/EDMX Tools, was causing the problems.

Disabling the add-in for normal use, and only enabling it when I need to use it, fixed the problem.

Microsoft was kind enough not to charge me for the incident. Phew.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Microsoft support about this issue - a solution hasn't been found yet, but it looks like it may be a corrupted Visual Studio installation, but it's interesting that it only affects one particular solution and not other projects.

I'll post an update once a final solution is found.

Comment: Did you get this fixed? I get the same error with a 3rd party Outlook Add-in when I have both my add-in and theirs running at the same time. All is fine if I just run mine, or just run theirs.

Comment: Yes, see my new answer/response.

Comment: Mine turned out to be a bug with the .Net framework, had to install fix KB981574